# Run make file as all process

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've create this simple makefile and I want to run all the process witn `make`

while do that it run only the first section `module1` and not `module2`,
what am I missing here ?

```
.PHONY: module1
module1:
    @echo "run module 1"
    DIR=$(PWD)
    @echo $(DIR)



.PHONY: module2
module2:
       @echo "run module2"
```

if I run `make module2` the module2 is executed successfully but I want all to be run in the `make` command and as far as I read in the net this is how it should work, what was wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html)...

> By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting
>   targets that start with a period). Therefore, makefiles are usually
>   written so that the first target is for compiling the entire program
>   or programs they describe. If the first rule in the makefile has
>   several targets, only the first target in the rule becomes the default
>   goal, not the whole list. You can manage the selection of the default
>   goal from within your makefile using the .DEFAULT_GOAL variable (see
>   Other Special Variables).

So you just need to provide a suitable default target -- `all` is `traditional'...

```
all: module1 module2
```

So the complete `makefile` would be...

```
all: module1 module2

.PHONY: module1
module1:
    @echo "run module 1"
    DIR=$(PWD)
    @echo $(DIR)

.PHONY: module2
module2:
    @echo "run module2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a good tutorial   (which not related to `c` programing language ) on make file that you can recommend?

Comment: Regarding tutorials, the [gnu make docs.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) are as good a starting point as any.  You might also want to look at [Oreilly's "Managing Projects with GNU Make"(pdf)](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/) -- although it may be slightly dated.

Comment: thanks, see please  if you can also help here :),https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022628/path-in-makefile-not-working