# path in makefile not working

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Im running the following `makefile` 
which needs to change `dir` to specific target and run there `npm install`

The problem is that I was able to see in the output that it print the directory (project/app) to the right directory but the installation (npm install) run on level up (project), why ?

For example

When I run it I see from cd $(DIR)/app
`/Users/i03432/go/src/project/app`

Now the second command is 
`npm install`

And I got error  that id doesn’t find the package json in the project path which is right... it’s only in the `app` path. Why the cd is not working ?

it try to find it here
`/Users/i03432/go/src/project/package.json`

and here is the package.json

`/Users/i03432/go/src/project/app/package.json`

The makefile is

```
module:

   DIR=$(PWD)
   @echo $(DIR)
   cd $(DIR)/app
   npm install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every command in a rule is run in a single process (sub-shell). Every change you perform on the environment is hence tied to that particular line. You want to change your snippet to

```
cd $(PWD)/app && npm install
```

This command runs in a single subprocess and should yield the desired result. Note that this problem occurs for the definition of `DIR`, too, so you might want to move this a few lines up:

```
DIR = $(PWD)

module:
    cd $(DIR) && npm install
```

This way, you are referring to a variable that `make` provides, and you don't rely upon subprocesses here.

Comment: Thanks +1 , in case i've additional command I guess I should add `npm install && npm prune ` but in case the first command `npm install` was failed how should I finish the command chain ?

Comment: If `npm prune` shall be executed in any case, you can chain it like this: `cd $(DIR) && npm install; npm prune`

Comment: No, the `prune` should run just if the `install` was done successfully

Comment: Then yes, you can chain anything you like with `&&`

Comment: and the second will executed only if the first was finish successfully ?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.